# Jquery find 'pre' apply css

Tags: jquery, css, find, pre

I'm using jquery to fetch some data and so far so good.  Can I apply styling to the retrieved data?  I would like to add a solid horizontal line after each pre tag.

```
$.get(dataSrc, function (data) {
      success:  function () {
       var tags = $(data).find('pre');
       $("#div1").empty().append(tags);
       };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an `each` statement

```
$('pre', $(data)).each(function(){
    // 'this' refers to the pre element
    $(this).append(your_line);
})
```